# Datastore partition using namespace api

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, multi-tenant

I want to use Multitenancy feature of GAE in my app's datastore. [Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/) they have given that

> Using the Namespaces API, you can easily partition data across tenants simply by specifying a unique namespace string for each tenant.

so my questions are,

[1.]How many partition(of one datastore)  can  be created using namespace api?

[2.]Is there any limit on the size  of each partition?

[3.]how would I know if size of a partition is increased beyond GAE free quota?

i'll really appreciate any help to clear this doubt.

thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How many partition(of one datastore) can be created using namespace api?**

Namespaces help you increase your app scalability, you have no limit number

**Is there any limit on the size of each partition?**

App engine Free quota is fixed, it's the only limit. If you need to activate billing, you'll have to fix the limit budget. App engine offers you a very high scalability

**how would I know if size of a partition is increased beyond GAE free quota?**

As for second question, you have a quota for the whole application, not per namespace. If you consume all the free resources your app will throw an error instead of serving the appropriate handler, until the quota is replenished